# How to show algebraically that $x^3 +3x +1$ is injective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How to show algebraically that $$x^3 +3x +1$$ is injective?

Working with the usual method of assuming that $f(c)=f(d)$ and then seeing if $c=d$. I've tried several approaches, including factoring by the difference of cubes, followed by use of the quadratic formula. I'm stumped. Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Bob

Comment: Show that it is monotone.

Comment: You cannot show it "purely algebraically" because the function is not injective on $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 12):

Notice $$\begin{align}
f(x) - f(y) &= (x^3 + 3x + 1) - (y^3 + 3y+1)\\
&= (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2 + 3)\\
&= \frac12 (x-y)( x^2 + (x+y)^2 + y^2 + 6)\end{align}$$
Since $x^2 + (x+y)^2 + y^2 + 6 \ne 0$ for any pair of real numbers $x, y$;
we have $f(x) \ne f(y)$ whenever $x \ne y$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^3+3x+1$, let's suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(y)\quad \iff\quad x^3+3x+1&=y^3+3y+1\\
x^3-y^3+3(x-y)&=0
\end{align*}
We can factor $x^3-y^3$ as $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$, so
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(y)\quad \iff(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+3)&=0
\end{align*}
Since $$x^2+xy+y^2=(x+\frac{1}{2}y)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\ge 0$$ we have $$x^2+xy+y^2+3\ge 3$$
Then
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(y)\quad \iff x-y&=0 \iff x=y
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

$$
f(x)=f(y)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x^3+3x+1=y^3+3y+1,
$$
hence
$$
0=x^3-y^3+3(x-y)=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+3).\tag{1}
$$
But
$$
x^2+xy+y^2+3=\Big(x+\frac{y}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{3y^2}{4}+3>0,
$$
and thus $(1)$ implies that $x=y$.